# Javascript click and hold on element using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, events, dhtml

I need to have some functionality in my web app where a specific action occurs when the user clicks and holds on an element. Think of it like the long press on Android.

I have my div:

```
<div id="myDiv"
  onmousedown="press()"
  onmouseup="cancel()"
  onmouseout="cancel()"
  onmousemove="cancel()">Long Click Me</div>
```

and my javascript:

```
var down = false;

function press()
{
  down = true;
  setTimeout(function() { action(); }, 1500);
}

function cancel()
{
  down = false; // this doesn't happen when user moves off div while holding mouse down!
}

function action()
{
  if (!down)
    return; // if the flag is FALSE then do nothing.

  alert("Success!");
  down = false;
}
```

This works as long as all I do is press and hold on the element. I have the `onmouseout` and `onmousemove` events to call cancel() because I want the user to have the option to change their mind and move the mouse off the element before action() starts.

Unfortunately, it seems that my code does not do this.
In fact, if the use clicks down for a moment, moves the mouse off the div and releases *before* the 1.5 sec then action() won't bail out as expected.

**Edit**: Thanks for your input everyone but it turns out I'm just a little bit *special* and didn't see that I forgot a capital letter in my HTML in my onmouseout. The sample code I gave above should work exactly as expected.

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers or just some? why not make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to let other people test it? Also dont use bool, just use `var`, JavaScript is dynamically typed.

Comment: I had var in my code, I accidentally wrote bool when I wrote this example.

Comment: Guys, stop answering. I asked the question wrong, I'm sorry. The issue is not that action() is starting - I have a test: if(!down)return; so it's not an issue. The issue is that cancel() isn't being called if the user moves the mouse off the div with the mouse button pressed. This is just a toy example to illustrate my problem; I actually *need* to have cancel() called when they move off the div before 1.5 sec otherwise short click won't work afterwards, etc.

Comment: did you put alert('cancel called') in the cancel function to see if it really is not called? I think, as in my answer, that if (!down) returns false because down is a function and no longer a variable

Comment: No, the problem was a typo in my onmouseout. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course action() is still called.  You didn't actually cancel the `setTimeout()` function.  I would suspect that maybe in your real code, you have a scoping issue and maybe aren't testing the same version of the `done` variable that you think you are.

A better way than using the `down` flag would be to keep track of the return value from `setTimeout()` and actually cancel the timer in the `cancel()` function.  Then, `action()` will never fire when you don't want it to.  I think it's also technically a more correct behavior when you mouseout to cancel any chance of the timer firing.

Also, there is no such thing as:

```
bool down = false;
```

in javascript.  It would have to be:

```
var down = false;
```

I would recommend this code:

```
var downTimer = null;

function down()
{
  cancel();
  downTimer = setTimeout(function() { action(); }, 1500);
}

function cancel()
{
  if (downTimer) 
  {
    clearTimeout(downTimer);
    downTimer = null;
  }
}

function action()
{
  downTimer = null;
  alert("Success!");
}
```

Comment: 1) see my comment on the main question: I made a typo when when writing the example Q, I had var. 2) Did you notice that the first 2 lines of action() tests to see the `down` flag? I guess I should have phrased the question better: change "Why is action() still being called" to "Why isn't action() bailing out as expected?"

Comment: In your real code, I would suspect a scoping problem on your `down` variable such that you aren't testing the same copy of the `down` variable you think you are.  Your sample as you have it written here (when you correct the typo) looks to me like it should work.  But, I think it's still better to cancel the timer rather than just set the flag and I think it's slightly more correct behavior when the mouse leaves.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a typo in my onmouseout in my div. I forgot an uppercase letter. Why doesn't Zend have autocomplete on javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

You also need to clear the timeout in your cancel function - otherwise it will still fire - as you initiated it in the down function.

so..

```
bool down = false;
//your timeout var
var t;

function down()
{
  down = true;
  t = setTimeout(function() { action(); }, 1500);
}

function cancel()
{
  down = false;
clearTimeout(t);
}

function action()
{
  if (!down)
    return;

  alert("Success!");
  down = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to cancel the timeout in the cancel() function, use

```
var mytimer = null;

function ondown(){mytimer = setTimeOut('action()', 1500;)}   

function cancel(){clearTimeout(mytimer);}
function action(){mytimer=null; alert('success!');}
```

also note that you used `down` first as a variable end then as a function... Calling `if(!down)` will always return false because `down` refers to a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code as I see it.

First

```
bool down = false;
```

is not valid JavaScript. It should be

```
var down = false;
```

Then you have two variables called `down`: the boolean value and the function. The function will overwrite the variable, until as such time that you execute one of the statements that sets `down` to true or false.

As others have said: once set, the deferred function will continue to be executed 1.5 seconds later, unless you cancel the timeout. But then again it doesn't matter, since you do check to see if the mouse button is down before doing anything.

So I'd say rename the boolean variable to `isMouseDown` or something and try again.